# How can reactive extensions and/or actor model simplify process orchestration?

Tags: java, akka, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am implementing a module where my main process spawns a set of parallel and sequential child processes (tasks) to complete its work. The tasks themselves are mainly fetching data from various sources and performing computations. Some are CPU- while others are IO-bound.

The current implementation uses Java Executor/Completion service in multiple steps to achieve this. An example of this process workflow can be depicted as follows:

Task A1 ---------------->
Task0 -> Task A2 ---------------->
                       Task A3 -> Task B1 ->  Task C (combines results from all tasks to generate output)
                                         Task B2 ->
                       Task A4 --------------->

Tasks `A1`-`A4` run in parallel, and so does tasks `B1` and `B2`. Finally, the task `C` depends on all the tasks `A`'s and `B`'s to compile the final output.

Building this using Executor service didn't seem very clean and I've been looking for better ways to do this as these task dependencies could change or increase in complexity with time and having `Futures` and `Callable` to manage them can get uglier over time.

I've been exploring the topic a little and came across **reactive extensions** and **actor model** frameworks. Akka has seemed a little too much for this while RxJava on a high level seemed like a reasonable fit that would simplify and make the design more extensible due to its stream/event-based processing pattern.

Some of the examples in [RxJava Threading Examples](http://www.grahamlea.com/2014/07/rxjava-threading-examples/) have also looked quite promising.

I'm here to seek for some advice from the community as to whether this is the right approach and if there are other ways/better frameworks to solve such problems.

=====================================================================================================

Wrote the following using JGraphT but still need to figure out how to reuse the thread pools. As in this case I end up creating new Thread Executors for each request. Posting main parts of the code here which should give an idea of the approach.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.traverse.TopologicalOrderIterator;

public class GraphTaskExecutor {

    ThreadExecutor executor;
    private List<Result> results;
    private List<TaskInfo> log;
    private DirectedGraph<GraphTask, DefaultEdge> graph;
    Set<GraphTask> executing;

    public GraphTaskExecutor() {
        executor = new ThreadExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime()
                .availableProcessors() * 4, 60,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        results = new ArrayList<Result>();
        log = new ArrayList<TaskInfo>();
        executing = new HashSet<GraphTask>();
    }

    public List<Result> execute(Request request, List<GraphTask> tasks) {
        System.out.println("Preparing task runner. Num Tasks: " + tasks.size());
        graph = new GraphTaskBuilder(tasks).buildGraph();
        processTasks();
        awaitCompletion();
        return results;
    }

    private void awaitCompletion() {
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.DAYS);
            System.out.println("Results " + results.toString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processTasks() {
        if (graph.vertexSet().size() == 0) {
            executor.shutdown();
            System.out
                    .println("All tasks completed... shutting down executor service");
        } else {
            synchronized (graph) {
                Iterator<GraphTask> iter = new TopologicalOrderIterator<GraphTask, DefaultEdge>(
                        graph);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    GraphTask task = iter.next();
                    if (graph.incomingEdgesOf(task).size() == 0
                            && !executing.contains(task)) {
                        executor.execute(task);
                        executing.add(task);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void completed(GraphTask t) {
        System.out.println("Completed Task: " + t.getName());
        synchronized (graph) {
            for (DefaultEdge edge : graph.outgoingEdgesOf(t)) {
                GraphTask target = graph.getEdgeTarget(edge);
                target.addData(t.getData());
            }
            if (t.isEndPoint())
                results.add(t.getResult());
            graph.removeVertex(t);
            executing.remove(t);
        }
        processTasks();
    }

    private class ThreadExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
        public ThreadExecutor(int corePoolSize, long keepAliveSeconds,
                BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
            super(corePoolSize, corePoolSize, keepAliveSeconds,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
        }

        @Override
        protected void beforeExecute(Thread thread, Runnable runTask) {
            super.beforeExecute(thread, runTask);
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable runTask, Throwable e) {
            super.afterExecute(runTask, e);
            completed((GraphTask) runTask);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        GraphTaskExecutor graphTaskExecutor = new GraphTaskExecutor();
        TaskContext context = new TaskContext();
        List<GraphTask> tasks = new ArrayList<GraphTask>();
        Request request = new Request(1);

        Set<DataType> empty = new HashSet<DataType>();
        Set<DataType> producer = new HashSet<DataType>(Arrays.asList(
                DataType.ACCT_INFO, DataType.PROJECTIONS));
        Set<DataType> consumer = new HashSet<DataType>(Arrays.asList(
                DataType.ACCT_INFO, DataType.PROJECTIONS));
        Set<DataType> accountResult = new HashSet<DataType>(
                Arrays.asList(DataType.ACCT_INFO));
        Set<DataType> projectionResult = new HashSet<DataType>(
                Arrays.asList(DataType.PROJECTIONS));
        Set<DataType> intraDayResult = new HashSet<DataType>(
                Arrays.asList(DataType.PROJECTIONS));

        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "1", "A", producer, empty, empty));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "2", "X", producer, consumer, empty,
                "A"));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "3", "Y", producer, consumer,
                accountResult, "A"));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "4", "B", producer, consumer, empty,
                "A"));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "5", "C", producer, consumer, empty,
                "B"));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "6", "D", producer, consumer,
                intraDayResult, "C"));
        tasks.add(new GraphTask(context, "7", "E", producer, consumer,
                projectionResult, "D", "X", "Y"));

        graphTaskExecutor.execute(request, tasks);
        System.out.println("All DONE");

    }

}


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class GraphTask extends AbstractTask {

    private Set<String> dependencies = new TreeSet<String>();

    public GraphTask(TaskContext context, String id, String name,
            Set<DataType> produces, Set<DataType> consumes,
            Set<DataType> endpoints, String... dependency) {
        super(id, name, context, produces, consumes, endpoints);
        dependencies.addAll(Arrays.asList(dependency));
    }

    public GraphTask(TaskContext context, String id, String name,
            Set<DataType> produces, Set<DataType> consumes,
            Set<DataType> endpoints) {
        super(id, name, context, produces, consumes, endpoints);
    }

    public void addDependency(String dependency) {
        this.dependencies.add(dependency);
    }

    public Data process(TaskContext context, Data data) throws TaskException {
        int time = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println("Task " + getName() + " estimated to run for "
                + time + " secs");
        TaskResult result = null;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result = new TaskResult(getName());
        for (DataType d: getProduces()) {
            result.addData(d, d.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Set<String> getDependencies() {
        return dependencies;
    }

    public void setDependencies(Set<String> dependencies) {
        this.dependencies = dependencies;
    }

}

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public abstract class AbstractTask implements Task<Data, Result> {

    private String identifier;
    private String name;
    private TaskContext context;
    private List<Data> prevData;
    private Data data;
    private Set<DataType> produces;
    private Set<DataType> consumes;
    private Set<DataType> endpoints;
    private TaskStatus status;
    private LocalTime startTime;
    private LocalTime endTime;
    private Result result;

    public AbstractTask(String id, String name, TaskContext context,
            Set<DataType> produces, Set<DataType> consumes,
            Set<DataType> endpoints) {
        this.identifier = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
        this.consumes = consumes;
        this.produces = produces;
        this.endpoints = endpoints;
        this.data = new Data();
        this.prevData = new ArrayList<Data>();
        this.status = TaskStatus.SUCCESS;
    }

    public AbstractTask(String id, String name, TaskContext context) {
        this(id, name, context, new HashSet<DataType>(),
                new HashSet<DataType>(), new HashSet<DataType>());
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public TaskContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(TaskContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isEndPoint() {
        return (endpoints.size() > 0);
    }

    private Data preProcess() throws MissingDataException,
            SkippedTaskException, ErrorTaskException {
        Map<TaskStatus, Data> statusData = new HashMap<TaskStatus, Data>();
        Map<DataType, Object> allData = new HashMap<DataType, Object>();

        // Get all data from previous results
        for (Data r : prevData) {
            statusData.put(r.getStatus(), r);
            allData.putAll(r.getObjects());
        }

        Data data = new Data();
        data.addData(allData);
        data.setStatus(deriveTaskStatus(statusData));

        switch (data.getStatus()) {
        case SUCCESS:
            for (DataType d : consumes) {
                if (!allData.containsKey(d)) {
                    throw new MissingDataException("Task " + name + " Missing input data for "
                            + d);
                }
            }
            break;
        case SKIPPED:
            throw new SkippedTaskException("Previous Task was skipped");
        case ERROR:
            throw new ErrorTaskException("Previous Task failed");
        }
        return data;
    }

    private TaskStatus deriveTaskStatus(Map<TaskStatus, Data> statusData) {
        if (statusData.containsKey(TaskStatus.ERROR))
            return TaskStatus.ERROR;
        if (statusData.containsKey(TaskStatus.SKIPPED))
            return TaskStatus.SKIPPED;
        return TaskStatus.SUCCESS;
    }

    private Result postProcess(Data outputData) throws MissingDataException {
        Result result = new Result();
        for (DataType d : endpoints) {
            if (!outputData.getObjects().containsKey(d)) {
                throw new MissingDataException("Missing end point data for " + d);
            }
            result.addData(d, outputData.getObject(d));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running task: " + name);
        try {
            Data inputData = preProcess();
            data = process(context, inputData);
            result = postProcess(data);
        } catch (MissingDataException | SkippedTaskException
                | ErrorTaskException e) {
            data = new Data(TaskStatus.SKIPPED, new Error("SKIP_TASK",
                    "Skip Task", e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TaskException e) {
            data = new Data(TaskStatus.ERROR, new Error("PREV_ERROR",
                    "Error in dependent task", e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public abstract Data process(TaskContext context, Data data)
            throws TaskException;

    @Override
    public void addData(Data data) {
        this.prevData.add(data);
    }

    public TaskStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(TaskStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public Set<DataType> getProduces() {
        return produces;
    }

    public void setProduces(Set<DataType> produces) {
        this.produces = produces;
    }

    public Set<DataType> getConsumes() {
        return consumes;
    }

    public void setConsumes(Set<DataType> consumes) {
        this.consumes = consumes;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public TaskInfo getTaskInfo() {
        return new TaskInfo(this.identifier, this.name, this.status,
                this.startTime, this.endTime);
    }

    public Set<DataType> getEndpoints() {
        return endpoints;
    }

    public void setEndpoints(Set<DataType> endpoints) {
        this.endpoints = endpoints;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out Java 8's CompletableFuture. You can submit tasks to the fork join pool and hook up functions or further tasks to be called when the tasks are done.  You could combine that with Java 8 Streams too.

Comment: Thanks @Jacek for the edits. With CompleteableFuture I may end up hand holding tasks at each stage and perhaps wont be a generic solution for submitting a topology of tasks. Followed an approach someone posted to write my own Graph Executor. Please refer to an example above. It works but then I end up creating new ThreadExecutor for each request. Was thinking if there is anyway I can reuse the thread pool. The shutdown in case of last task prevents me from doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Rx-Java would be a good option here as it's designed to build sophisticated message flows, fork and join parallel executions inside your app (just another compile dependency). While CPU bound tasks could end up with a simple callback, IO bound require async IO support (you can also do it yourself with rx-java).

Akka and Vert.x are complete frameworks to build applications compared to Rx-Java being just a library to bring advantages of asynchronous functional programming into your app.